# Invoke-Sqlcmd unable to create a connection

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following Powershell command:

```
$DATABASE="adventureworks"
$SQLSERVER="PerfSQL02"

invoke-sqlcmd -Query "sp_whoisactive" -database $DATABASE -hostname $SQLSERVER
```

The database name and SQLServer are valid and I'm running as my local user, who is sysadmin on the instance and dbo of the database. Additionally, I can connect through SSMS and run sp_whoisactive quite nicely.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Cannot open database "adventureworks" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user '<myusername>'
```

I'm sure I'm missing something excruciatingly simple, but it's been awhile since I've used `Invoke-sqlcmd`, what am I missing that is making it unable to connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I should have used `-serverinstance` rather than `-hostname` as the `-serverinstance` argument passes the server and instance name.